# Pythonic way of subclassing a list

Tags: python, data-structures, subclass

Here's my general problem space:

I have a byte/bit protocol with a device over I2C.

I've got a "database" of the commands to fully describe all the bitfields types and values and enumerations.

I have a class to consume the database and a i2c driver/transactor so that I can then call commands and get responses.

```
MyProtocol = Protocol('database.xml',I2CDriver())
theStatus = MyProtocol.GET_STATUS()
```

creates the proper byte stream for the GET_STATUS command, sends it over the i2c and returns the response as a byte array currently.  I can get it to pretty print the response inside of the GET_STATUS() implementation, but I want to move that behavior to return object, rather than in the command.

I want my return object to be 'smart':  `theStatus` needs to have the list/array of bytes plus a reference to its field definitions.

I want `theStatus` to act like an list/bytearray, so I can directly inspect the bytes.  I don't care if slices are anything other than lists of bytes or bytearray.   Once they've been sliced out they're just bytes.

I want 'theStatus' to be able to be printed `print(theStatus)` and have it pretty print all the fields in the status.  I'm comfortable on how to make this happen once I settle on a workable data structure that allows me to access the bytes and the data base.

I want to inspect `theStatus` by field name with something like `theStatus.FIELDNAME` or maybe `theStatus['FIELDNAME']'`.   Same thing:  once I have a workable data structure that has the byte array and database as members, I can make this happen.

The problem is I don't know the "right" data structure to cause the least amount of problems.

Any suggestions on the most pythonic way to accomplish this?  My initial thought was to subclass `list` and add the field definitions as a member, but it seems like python doesn't like that idea at all.

Composition seems like the next bet, but getting it to act like a proper `list` seems like that might be a bunch of work to get it 'right'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you really want is to implement a new [*sequence* type](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), one that is perhaps mutable. You can either create one from scratch by implementing the [special methods needed to emulate container types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types), or you can use a suitable [`collections.abc` collection ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) as a base.

The latter is probably the easiest path to take, as the ABCs provide implementations for many of the methods as base versions that rely on a few abstract methods you must implement.

For example, the (immutable) [`Sequence` ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) only requires you to provide implementations for `__getitem__` and `__len__`; the base ABC implementation provides the rest:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

class StatusBytes(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, statusbytes):
        self._bytes = statusbytes

    def __getitem__(self, idx_or_name):
        try:
            return self._bytes[idx_or_name]
        except IndexError:
            # assume it is a fieldname
            return FIELDNAMES[idx_or_name]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._bytes)
```

If you really need a full list implementation, including support for rich comparisons (`list_a <= list_b`), sorting (`list_a.sort()`), copying [`list_a.copy()`] and multiplication (`list_a * 3`), then there is also the [`collections.UserList()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList). This class inherits from `collections.abc.MutableSequence`, and adds the extra functionality that `list` offers over the base sequence ABCs. If you *don't* need that extra functionality, stick to base ABCs.

Comment: I've done this and it's working fine.  I actually went with `UserList` for some reason (extend maybe?  something like that)   Out of curiosity, why isn't there a call to super() in `__init__`?

Comment: @RussSchultz: in the `__init__` of `UserList` or in the `__init__` I defined in my example class? `super().__init__()` is not always appropriate, and requires that all `__init__` methods in the MRO can handle the same number of arguments. That makes using it not so cut and dry. The ABCs in `collections.abc` have no `__init__` methods, there is no need to use `super().__init__()` here unless you want to support further subclassing with multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for [collections.UserList](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList).

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass which inherits from `collections.UserList`, that's exactly what its for  https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList